# creating repeated index in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
library(data.table)
     dt <- fread('

Product  Index2
A          1
B          1
C          2
D          2
E          3
               ')
```

So the `Index2` column is my desired column. I am trying to create it by:

```
dt[,Index2:=rep(1:nrow(dt), each=2)]
```

but I am getting error messages:

> "Supplied 2774 items to be assigned to 1387 items of column 'Index2'" and 
>   "Coerced 'integer' RHS to 'double' to match the column's type".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `length.out` to clip the `length`.

```
dt[, Index3 := rep(1:.N, each=2, length.out=.N)]
dt
#   Product Index2 Index3
#1:       A      1      1
#2:       B      1      1
#3:       C      2      2
#4:       D      2      2
#5:       E      3      3
```

---

Or another option is the `gl` function

```
dt[, Index3 := as.numeric(gl(.N, 2, .N))]
```

Or as @Frank mentioned

```
dt[, Index3 := (.I+1) %/% 2]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: A silly mathy alternative: `(.I+1) %/% 2`. Probably best to have it be an integer, not a float, though.

Answer (score 1):

Another option without using `rep`:

```
dt$Index2 <- ceiling(seq(nrow(dt))/2)
```